# Why is my custom function printing my row names in addition to the data?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, formatting, r-markdown

I have the following custom function that I am using to create a table of summary statistics in R.

```
regression.stats<-function(fit){
  formula<-fit$call;
  data<-eval(getCall(fit)$data);
  abserror<-abs(exp(fit$fitted.values)-data$bm)/exp(fit$fitted.values);
  QMLE<-exp((sigma(fit)^2)/2);
  smear<-sum(exp(fit$residuals))/nrow(data);
  RE<-mean(data$bm)/mean(exp(fit$fitted.values));
  CF<-(RE+smear+QMLE)/3;
  adjPE<-mean(abs((exp(fit$fitted.values)*CF)-data$bm)
               /(exp(fit$fitted.values)*CF));
  SEE<-exp(sigma(fit)+4.6052)-100;
  summary<-summary(fit)
  statistics<-data.frame("df"=fit$df.residual,
                     "r2"=round(summary(fit)$r.squared,4),
                     "adjr2"=round(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared,4),
                     "AIC"=AIC(fit),"BIC"=BIC(fit),
                     "logLik"=logLik(fit),
                     "PE"=round(mean(abserror)*100,2),QMLE=round(QMLE,3),
                     smear=round(smear,3),RE=round(RE,3),CF=round(CF,3),
                         "adjPE"=round(mean(adjPE)*100,2),
                         "SEE"=round(SEE,2),row.names = print(substitute(fit)));
return(statistics)
}
```

I want to bind the resulting rows into a data.frame in order to produce a table of comparison statistics between regression analyses. For example, using the data from the `mtcars` dataset...

```
data(mtcars)
lm1<-(cyl~mpg,data=mtcars)
lm2<-(cyl~disp,data=mtcars)
lm2<-(disp~mpg,data=mtcars)
rbind(regression.stats(lm1),regression.stats(lm2),regression.stats(lm3))
```

I am creating this for an R Markdown html file and I want readers to be able to tell which regression equation produced which statistics. However when I run the code it also ends up printing a list of the names of the `lm` functions in addition to the regression statistics in the resulting html document.

I have managed to track the problem down to the line `row.names = print(substitute(fit)))` in my function. If I remove that line it no longer prints the `lm` name when running the function. However, what happens then is my rows are no longer associated with the correct model name. **How can I adjust my function so that it only prints the name of the model function as the row name of the summary function, rather than creating an additional list?**

Comment: You have a `print` in the `row.names = print(substitute(fit))`

Comment: Why print? Why not just row.names =substitute (fit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
...
 row.names = print(substitute(fit))
...
```

should be

```
 row.names = deparse(substitute(fit))
```

Or simply `substitute(fit)` as this gets converted to `character`

as `print` doesn't have any return value and it is just printing on the console

---

After the change in function

```
rbind(regression.stats(lm1),regression.stats(lm2),regression.stats(lm3))
#   df     r2  adjr2       AIC       BIC     logLik  PE  QMLE        smear RE CF adjPE          SEE
#lm1 30 0.7262 0.7171  91.46282  95.86003  -42.73141 NaN 1.570 1.443000e+00 NA NA   NaN 1.585700e+02
#lm2 30 0.8137 0.8075  79.14552  83.54273  -36.57276 NaN 1.359 1.317000e+00 NA NA   NaN 1.189600e+02
#lm3 30 0.7183 0.7090 363.71635 368.11356 -178.85818 NaN   Inf 1.861805e+65 NA NA   NaN 1.092273e+31
```